# how to achieve userspace clock control in tinyalsa playback

Tags: android, audio, alsa

I'm just trying to understand tinyalsa, in which i could not see any clock control. So is it not possible to have a userspace clock control in tiny-alsa based playback? 
Also i dont see any sleep calls, so how buffer overflow is controlled in /dev/snd devices.

Comment: What do you mean with "clock control"?

Comment: I mean a hardware clock associated with the hardware decoder/mixer.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean. What corresponding function(s) from the full alsa-lib do you miss?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems to be achievable with the timer interface it seems. However, I'm not sure about this with tinyalsa.